# how many statistical distributions in real life?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

i mean when we are using the statistic in real life how many distributions do we need to know ?

- Normal
- Normal Log
- Poisson
- t student

and how many others , i ask in case i work with statistic some day

Comment: Wrong question: the definition of some exotic distribution can be checked in a book. Statistical work is something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Realistically, there is no limit. Commonly occurring 'named' distributions include uniform, normal (also called Gaussian), Bernoulli*, binomial*, Poisson*, beta, gamma (and its special cases chi-squared and exponential), Student's t, Snedecor's F.

Somewhat less commonly: Laplace, negative binomial* (and special case, geometric*), hypergeometric*, lognormal (which is *not* log of a normal), Weibull, Pareto, Rayleigh, etc.

These are only partial lists from memory, and in no particular order. I have put asterisks (*) after
'discrete' distributions in my list. The rest are 'continuous". Then there are many other useful distributions that do not (yet) have names.

As you may guess, mathematicians and statisticians are not shy about naming distributions they discover or use after themselves, mentors, or predecessors.
(Often the name of a distribution has little to do with it's origin or history, and some names differ by country.)

If you want to learn more about
any one of these distributions, look in indexes of applied probability and
mathematical statistics books. Also, you can google (with care); I have 
found Wikipedia to be almost always accurate.